# iPhone app unable to post to Facebook - This Message Contains Blocked Content

Tags: ios, facebook, blocked

We have an iPhone / iPad app that allows it's users to share various bits of their pregnancy experience, such as fetal development progress and milestones, baby kicks, contractions, etc.  The app has been around for a couple of years and we've never had any issues.

However, recently our users started to contact us about not being able to post their status.  After testing the app, we found that we are not getting the following error message:

"Warning: This Message Contains Blocked Content: Some content in this message has been reported as abusive by Facebook users."

It appears that our entire app is being blocked and our customers have been unable to post any messages from it.  Our users are extremely frustrated by this and it is resulting in negative reviews for our iPhone/iPad application.

Unfortunately, we have no control over this and would greatly appreciate any suggestions on how to fix this.

Thank you!

Comment: Might want to contact facebook directly on this one. You might be right in thinking that your whole app is being blocked.

Comment: Nothing you can do but contact facebook really.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because you should contact Facebook about this.